# ERROR ITMS-9000: Missing or invalid signature

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6, delphi-xe7

Everything were working fine, before iOS 8.
I've tried to change bundle name, I've recreated the certificate related to the application, but nothing helped so far.

I am on MacOS Maveric 10.9.2, with the XCode 6.1

Here some screenshots of the current config and the issue.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do those Delphi versions mean anything? Are you really wanting to compile on XE5, XE6 or XE7? Or did you just add them at random?

Comment: well. i've tried to compile on all of them, the issue is the same. this was my point of adding them.
The most important is if it became able to compile an publish at least with XE7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [hotfix](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/30022). "RAD Studio hotfix to enable deployment of Delphi and C++ iOS applications to the Apple App Store. This fix applies to RAD Studio XE5, XE6 and XE7."

Comment: I have patched with it, still the same.

Comment: Try signing a Hello World app in Xcode itself and using their app verifier to test it. Once you have that working the Delphi signing should also work. What I had to end up doing (but my error was different) was removing all certificates and profiles except for the exact one I needed. Also try using just a substring in the Distribution Certificate field instead of the entire name (this also worked for me). Finally, I've seen people uninstalling Xcode 6 and using Xcode 5. https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=108736&tstart=0 near the end.